# Latex Block diagramm / draw Range

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks

I want to use a Block diagram like in this document on page 9:
http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pst-bar/pst-bar-docDE.pdf

But I fail at doing this.
At the moment I am using this: [Grouped bar chart](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101320/grouped-bar-chart)

```
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 0.85*\textwidth,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    %ybar stacked,
    bar width=14pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Zeit in Sekunden},
    symbolic x coords={lokal,1 Gerät, 2 Geräte},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.25,
    ymin=0,
    nodes near coords,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(1,1.05)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex
    }
]
    \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(lokal,973) (1 Gerät,1426) (2 Geräte,698)};
    \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(lokal, 0.0) (1 Gerät,6.00) (2 Geräte,5.1)};
    \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(lokal,52) (1 Gerät,276) (2 Geräte,169)};

    \legend{Durchschnittliche Zeit zur Berechneung,Durchschnittliche Zeit zur Verteilung,Streuung gesamte Zeit}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

I want the diagram to be "block" style.
Alternatively I could draw a cross to show the Range of the results.
I need the horizontal line to be the average and the vertical line to be the range from minimum to maximum value.
I have no idea what packages, or command I have to use, to get what I want, so any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the source.  This is included in the TeX distribution, as far as I can tell.  It should be in the same path, just with `source` instead of `doc` as a DTX file.  (And  [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436))

Comment: Also, we usually don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @naturjoghurt Hi there! I'm not sure what is the problem you have, and you say nothing whether your code is working or not. I guess the simplest answer to your concern is that `pst` is not compatible with `PDF` (I don't know if your compiling with `pdflatex`) and also is independent of `TikZ`. Perhaps you can try to emulate the "block" style with `TikZ`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @naturjoghurt Can you explain (in English) how does the `block` style of `pst`works?

Comment: @Dox Yes, I am compiling with pdflatex. That is why pst did not work for me. The "block" style is used to display multiple values in one bar. The beginning and end of any bar can be adjusted, instead of just adjusting the height. With this style I want to show the minimum, maximum and range of my results. The minimum and maximum define the end and beginning of each bar and the range is the length of each bar. This way the values could be compared better, than using multiple bars.

Comment: run it with `xelatex` and you can use PSTricks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pst-bar}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{example.csv}
lokal, 1 Gerät, 2 Geräte
973, 1426, 698
0, 6, 5.1
52, 276, 169
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=0.5in,yunit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1.5)(3,15.5)
\psgrid[xunit=1.5in,gridlabels=0,subgriddiv=0,griddots=30](0,0)(1,15)
\psaxes[axesstyle=frame,dy=3,Dy=300,labels=y,ticks=y](0,0)(3,15)
\readpsbardata{\data}{example.csv}
\psbarchart[barstyle=red,chartstyle=block,yunit=0.01]{\data}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

or with `pdflatex --shellescape <file>` use

```
[...]
\usepackage{pst-bar}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
[...]
```

[image]

Comment: Seems to be the right solution, but when I compile this with XeLatex I get some Errors:
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ätD not set up for use with LaTeX.
And so on. I do not get these when compiling with Latex and letting the graphic out. Any idea, why I get these Errors when compiling with XeLatex?

Comment: with `xelatex`you have to delete the line with `inputenc` it is by default `utf8` and the one with `fontenc`. Use instead `\usepackage{fontspec}`

Comment: That solved the Problem. This is the right answer for my Problem, but the look of the XeLatex output is different.

Comment: I get the same one.