# undefined subtable

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfloats

Question below has been solved. The script has been edited.

I have find a template of subtable from this forum, but I can´t run it without errors. How can I solve this?

Error msg:

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment subtable undefined.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
! LaTeX Error: \begin{table} on input line 164 ended by \end{subtable}.
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{4F81BD}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{C0504D}
\definecolor{ggreen}{HTML}{9BBB59}
\definecolor{ppurple}{HTML}{9F4C7C}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}   
\centering
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.3*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.4},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {\%},
        symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(A, 100) (B,100) (C,100)};

        \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(A, 106) (B,113) (C,177)};
        \legend{MADYMO,Vivo}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Phase 1}
\end{subtable}
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering 
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width  = 1.3*\textwidth,
        height = 8cm,
        enlarge y limits={upper, value=0.4},
        ymin=0,
        major x tick style = transparent,
        ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
        bar width=20pt,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        ylabel = {\%},
        symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
        xtick = data,
        nodes near coords,
        scaled y ticks = false,
        enlarge x limits=0.25,
        ymin=0,
        legend cell align=left,
        legend style={
                at={(1,1.05)},
                anchor=south east,
                column sep=1ex
        }
    ]
        \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none]}]
            coordinates {(A, 100) (B,100) (C,100)};

        \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
             coordinates {(A, 98) (B,113) (C,178)};
        \legend{X,Y}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Phase 2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{aaaaaaa}
\label{tab:EmMaxPE_bar_X}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\usepackage{subfig}` with `\usepackage{subcaption}`? Also, which template exactly were you referring to?

Comment: In addition to loading the `subcaption` package, don't you also need to load one or more TikZ-related packages? Please specify them.

Comment: It worked, thank you!By the way, if I enlarge the table, how can i make sure it still centered? With template I mean this one:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101320/grouped-bar-chart/101323#101323 @TorbjørnT.

Comment: @Vivian - Since the code you've provided a link to features the instruction `width  = 0.85*\textwidth`, the `tikzpicture` environment will automatically fit inside the `subtable`. (The pictures don't look centered at first glance, but that's just because there's a `%` symbol located far to the right of the vertical axis.)

Comment: @Mico I am not sure why, but the bar table is not centered if I change the (width=1.3*\textwidth). 0.85 is too small for my table. Do u know how to modify it?

Comment: That is always the case for things that are wider than the textblock, they stick out on the right side. I don't really have time to look at that right now, but if you haven't gotten a solution later tonight I'll see if I can come up with something.

Comment: @Vivian - If you make the `tikzpicture` environment wider than the enclosing `subtable` environment, there is simply no way that the associated caption can be centered on the picture.

Comment: I see, now I see the reason why! Thank you ! @Mico

Comment: @Vivian : in this site, we keep questions separated from answers. Thus, in order to be understandable (and valuable) for future users, your should not update your question with the given answer.

Comment: @ebo ah, ok, I didnt know that, I thought it´s better not to open too many new question pages. Thank you !

Comment: It is actually better (you might find information in the [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)) to keep it simple: one question = one single issue you try to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Remark: I posted this question *before* the OP applied several substantial edits to the query. For instance, the `subcaption` environment wasn't being loaded in the initial form of the query, and there was no information about important aspects of the `tikzpicture` environments.)

To use `subtable` environments, you need to load the `subcaption` package. The `subfig` package does *not* provide a `subtable` environment.

In the following example, I've replaced the two `tikzpicture` environments with dummy `tabular` environments to simplify the exposition. (Also, you didn't indicate *which* tikz-related packages should be loaded or how `rred`, `bblue` etc. are defined.) Observe that you should insert a `%` (comment) character immediately after the first `subtable` environment if you want them to fit side-by-side.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}   
%\centering  <--- not needed!
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
   % dummy 'tabular' env.
   \begin{tabular}{lll}
   \toprule
   aaa bbb ccc\\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\caption{Phase 1}
\end{subtable}% <--- new
\begin{subtable}{.5\textwidth}
\centering 
   % dummy 'tabular' env.
   \begin{tabular}{lll}
   \toprule
   xxx yyy zzz\\
   \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
\caption{Phase 2}
\end{subtable}
\caption{aaaaaaa} \label{tab:EmMaxPE_bar_X}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You only need `\usepackage{pgfplots}` by the way, and if you want to test, change `rred` to `red`, and similar for `green` and `blue`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Indeed, the OP has since provided a link to the "template"; in that link, `bblue`, `rred`, etc are defined. Including the two `tikzpicture` environments instead of dummy `tabular` environments, while providing more visual excitement, changes nothing about needing to load the `subcaption` environment or needing to snug up the two `subtable` environments.

Comment: I do need the centering after \begin(table), otherwise the 2 tables will overlap each other. Due to the size of the table, I want to lie them in upper and lower part of the page, not side by side. But thank you for your suggestion. @Mico The caption is centered but not the table itself.

Comment: @Vivian - You write, "I do need the centering after `\begin(table)`, otherwise the 2 tables will overlap each other." That's not correct: The `table` environment contains two side-by-side `subtable` environments, which each have width `0.5\textwidth`. As long as you insert the `%` character after the first `subtable`, as I suggest doing, there will be no overlap. If `0.5\textwidth` simply is not big enough for your `tikzpicture` environments, you should consider loading the `rotating` package and using a `sidewaystable` environment instead of the current `table ` environment.

Comment: @Mico LaTex has a lot of functions which I berely know! Thank you, I will check how to use them!

Comment: Hi, Mico, I want to ask, in case I have 3 subtable (they are bar plots, which are placed in verticle direction), how can I make sure that the 3rd subtable also can be fully displayed? Now the 3rd subtable is only half displayed due to space is not enough I guess. I thought to use longtable, but seems I can´t use subtable in longtable environment. And I can´t just use longtable because I need to give 3 captions instead of 1. Do you have any idea how to make it work? Btw, I have tried with "\vspace" and "\newpage", but they don´t really help.@Mico

Comment: @Vivian - Hmmm, sounds like you should be using `figure` and `subfigure` environments, instead of `table` and `subtable` environments. (The LaTeX syntax is the same, just the names of the environments differ.) I take it that reducing the sizes of the plots to make all three of them fit on a single page is not an option. Do look at p. 21 of the user guide of the `caption` package; it discusses a macro called `\ContinuedFloat`, which should do exactly what you need to get done. Aim to place two `subfigure`s on one page and one `subfigure` on the next.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried. but I can´t use tikzpicture under figure environment. Or maybe I need sth extra to define it. @Mico

Comment: @Vivian - Please post a *new query* with the particulars of the problem you're looking to solve.