# How to color each column in a bar chart with different colors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart, bar

I have the following bar chart and I would like to color each column differently. Both columns are in the same plot, when I separate them just to give a different color values for each one the appearance of the bar chart changes. Is there a way to specify different colors for the same plot?

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}


\begin{document}




\begin{figure}
    \centering


     \subfloat[][name]{\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
                                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                                \begin{axis}[
                                symbolic x coords={col1, col2, col3},
                                xtick=data,
                                ylabel=Passed Challenges(\%),
                                xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
                                ymajorgrids,
                                bar width=17pt,
                                ]
                                \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB1] coordinates {
                                    (col1, 44.71) 
                                    (col2, 26.57) 
                                    (col3, 45.42) 
                                };
                                \end{axis}
                            \end{tikzpicture}}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: This post should help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/101320/121944

Answer (score 4):

Just do `\addplot`for each column with a defined color.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{bchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usepackage{subfig}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\definecolor{RYB2}{RGB}{245,245,245}
\definecolor{RYB1}{RGB}{218,232,252}
\definecolor{RYB4}{RGB}{108,142,191}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}
    \centering    

     \subfloat[][name]{\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
                                    \begin{tikzpicture}
                                \begin{axis}[
                                symbolic x coords={col1,,col2,,col3},
                                xticklabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north east},
                                xtick={col1,col2,col3},
                                ylabel=Passed Challenges(\%),
                                ymajorgrids,
                                bar width=17pt,
                                ]
                                \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB1] 
                                coordinates {(col1,44.71)};

                                \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB2] 
                                coordinates {(col2,26.57)};

                                \addplot[ybar,fill=RYB4] 
                                coordinates {(col3,45.42)};

                                \end{axis}
                            \end{tikzpicture}}}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the name of the second and third columns has eliminated

Comment: @User505 Should be fixed now. Added `col1,,col2,,col3` in `symbolic x coords` and `xtick`.

Comment: @AML Thanks for that comment, I had the exact same issue.